# How to change X object position smoothly while object with moving Y axis?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Object is moving by Y axis, i need to move X axis position smoothly.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
   playerRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(0.0f, 2.0f);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        if (newBallPos != 2)
        {
            Vector3 pos1 = this.transform.position;
            Vector3 pos2 = this.transform.position;
            pos2.x += 1f;
            StartCoroutine(Move_Routine(this.transform, pos1, pos2));
        }
    }

   ----
}

----

private IEnumerator Move_Routine(Transform transform, Vector3 from, Vector3 to)
{
    float t = 0f;
    while (t < 1f)
    {
        t += Time.deltaTime;

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(from, to, Mathf.SmoothStep(0f, 1f, t));
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

With this code. X axis changes, but with old Y axis position and it create's kind of shaking for time X axis moves.

On arrow click, i need to change Object X position smoothly, while still moving by Y axis.(I need to change X position by 1)

Appreciate for your help!

Comment: I recommend looking into a "tweening" package, such as LeanTween or DOTween (check the asset store)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the x axis to `Time.smoothDeltaTime;` in this method, values are averaged over several frames for a more smooth looking effect, it is a preference but sometimes can make a noticeable difference.

```
 pos2.x += Time.smoothDeltaTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

First as far as I understand you only want to smooth the X value of the position so you shoudl rather do

```
private IEnumerator Move_Routine(Transform transform, float from, float to)
{
    float t = 0f;
    while (t < 1f)
    {
        t += Time.deltaTime;

        // only lerp the single float value
        var currentX = Mathf.SmoothStep(from, to, t);

        // let the current other two values unchanged
        transform.position.x = currentX;

        yield return null;
    }

    // Just to be sure there is no under/overshooting I would
    // always set the fixed value in the end
    transform.position.x = to;
}
```

---

However, another issue in your case is that you are dealing with RigidBody.

1. You should not use `transform.position =` on rigidbodies at all but rather either `playerRigidbody.position =` or [`playerRigidbody.MovePosition(targetPosition)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html)
2. A Coroutine is executed every `Update` call but you should change rigidbodies only in `FixedUpdate` => you can use `WaitForFixedUpdate` in your coroutine
3. A third issue is that you might have multiple Coroutines running at the same time if you press the button again before the movement was finished. => you can solve this by a simply bool flag. Alternatively if you want to allow input (e.g. for moving in the other direction you should `StopCoroutine` the current routine first)

Therefore the jitter etc. So together:

```
private bool alreadyLerping;

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    playerRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(0.0f, 2.0f);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        // only do if not lerping laready otherwise input is ignored
        if (newBallPos != 2 && !alreadyLerping)
        {
            var currentX = transform.position.x;
            var targetX = currentX + 1.0f;
            StartCoroutine(Move_Routine(currentX, targetX));
        }
    }

    ...
}

// I just added an optional duration value
// if you do not pass it it will be 1 second as you had it
// but this way you can still make it faster or slower without having
// to hardcode
// you also don't have to pass in the transform or if you do you should not call it transform
private IEnumerator Move_Routine(float from, float to, float duration = 1.0f)
{
    if(alreadyLerping) yield break;

    alreadyLerping = true;

    var passedTime = 0f;

    do
    {
        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();

        var lerpfactor = passedTime / duration;

        var currentX = Mathf.SmoothStep(from, to, lerpfactor);

        playerRigidbody.MovePosition(new Vector3(currentX, transform.position.y, transform.position.z));

        passedTime += Time.deltaTime;

    } while (passedTime < duration);

    // Just to be sure there is no under/overshooting I would
    // always set the fixed value in the end
    playerRigidbody.MovePosition(new Vector3(to, transform.position.y, transform.position.z));

    // release the flag
    alreadyLerping = false;
}
```

or if you want the `StopCoroutine` variant

```
private IEnumerator currentRoutine;

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    playerRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(0.0f, 2.0f);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        // only do if not lerping laready otherwise input is ignored
        if (newBallPos != 2)
        {
            var currentX = transform.position.x;
            var targetX = currentX + 1.0f;

            if(currentRoutine!=null) StopCoroutine(currentRoutine);

            currentRoutine = Move_Routine(currentX, targetX);

            StartCoroutine(currentRoutine);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```